# How does symfony know which directory it's installed in?

Tags: php, git, symfony, architecture

I'm trying to establish a development process with symfony where developers can clone the symfony repository to their localhost and simply test their code on their computers. However I'm running into issues, of which git is not adding all the necessary files to copy (.gitignore issue), but also symfony doesn't know in which directory it is installed in when clearing the cache. Symfony is trying to clear it's cache stored in the wrong directory.

It seems that simply copy and pasting the symfony project and linking the apache server to the app_dev.php file doesn't work well. What would be a better approach when working with symfony with multiple people?

Comment: Why does symfony try to clear my cache in the wrong directory?

Comment: I don't use it but most likely it stores it in a `config` file or something. Find it and change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never pass your symfony application around as a copy when working with multiple people ... and even worse including the cache ...

use a cvs like git ( ignoring the cache folder ) and provide [DataFixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) and a [parameters.yml.dist](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file) in order to provide your co-workers with the latest development status and commented changes/commits.

The easiest way for your colleagues to have a running copy quickly would be providing a [Vagrantfile](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/index.html) including some provisioning.

This way you can make sure not only all your people have the same code-base but the same webserver, php-version/settings aswell.